# RecyclerView's IBinder RuntimeException, but it doesn't crash the app

Tags: android, performance, android-recyclerview, android-binder

I have kind-of-a problem. Although, it's a `RuntimeException` it doesn't crash app, but makes scrolling through `RecyclerView` laggy when scrolled faster. With each new row shown this logs come:

```
    Caught a RuntimeException from the binder stub implementation. java.lang.NullPointerException: 
Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.os.IBinder com.android.internal.textservice.ISpellCheckerSession.asBinder()' on a null object reference
                                                                         at android.view.textservice.SpellCheckerSession$SpellCheckerSessionListenerImpl.onServiceConnected(SpellCheckerSession.java:330)
                                                                         at android.view.textservice.SpellCheckerSession$InternalListener.onServiceConnected(SpellCheckerSession.java:473)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.textservice.ITextServicesSessionListener$Stub.onTransact(ITextServicesSessionListener.java:54)
                                                                         at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
```

Not much information about that one on the web. Maybe some of You had this kind of problem - performance I'd say and made it work without that one.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your adapter or activity deals with the [SpellCheckerService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/textservice/SpellCheckerService.html)

check your implementations and you'll find a null instance somewhere.

Comment: but I don't use it. Heck, I don't even know what `SpellCheckerService` is or how to use it...